# Asymptotic growth of the collection of Miller-Rabin pseudo-primes witnessed by a set

Tags: analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-number-theory

Consider a set $S$ of positive integers[*]. Define $P(S)$ as the set of numbers $N$ for which elements of $S$ are "witnesses" for the Miller-Rabin test for primality of $N$. Explicitly $P(S)=\cap_{s\in S} P(s)$ where $P(a)$ is the collection of $N$ for which $a$ is a "witness" for the Miller-Rabin test for primality of $N$; in other words, if $N=1+2^k r$ where $r$ is odd, then one of the following holds:

1. $a^r-1$ is divisible by $N$.
2. $a^{2^mr}+1$ is divisible by $N$ for some $m<k$.

If $P$ is the set of primes, then clearly $P\subset P(S)$. What can be said about the asymptotic growth of the complement $P(S)\setminus P$ for a fixed (but large) $S$?

[*]: The multiplicative nature of the Miller-Rabin test suggests that we take $S$ to be a set of primes.

Comment: The "reverse" problem has apprently been solved by Bach and Miller long ago![JSTOR 208811](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2008811)